# Hide certain product category in wordpress/woosommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried to hide a certain subcategory from the category widget on shop page and other pages, there is a category widget.
I found that the code below works for all pages except the shop page. If I change `is_product_category()` for the `is_shop()`, so it works for the shop page, but not for the other pages.

How can I do that it works for ALL pages (shop and all others)?

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

  $new_terms = array();

  // if a product category and on the shop page
  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_product_category() ) {

    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'seinakellad','nastennye-chasy','wall-clock' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }

    }

    $terms = $new_terms;
  }

  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the check for `is_product_category` & `in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies )` and it will work for everything else (except admin).

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you SOO mutch!

Comment: Added an answer to make you able to close this question. Just checkmark it. I've also improved your code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the additional check in your `if` condition:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'filter_get_terms', 10, 3 );
function filter_get_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = [];

    // if a product category and on the shop page
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, [ 'seinakellad', 'nastennye-chasy', 'wall-clock' ] ) ) {
                $new_terms[] = $term;
            }
        }

        $terms = $new_terms;
    }

    return $terms;
}
```